# Sort array in ascending order while minimizing "cost"

Tags: algorithm

I'm taking comp 2210 (Data Structures) next semester and I've been doing the homework for the summer semester that is posted online.  Until now, I've had no problems doing the assignments.  Take a look at assignment 4 below, and see if you can give me a hint as to how to approach it. Please don't provide a complete algorithm, just an approach. Thanks!

A “costed sort” is an algorithm in which a sequence of values must be arranged in ascending order. The sort is
carried out by interchanging the position of two values one at a time until the sequence is in the proper order. Each
interchange incurs a cost, which is calculated as the sum of the two values involved in the interchange. The total
cost of the sort is the sum of the cost of the interchanges.

> For example, suppose the starting
>   sequence were {3, 2, 1}. One possible
>   series of interchanges is

```
Interchange 1: {3, 1, 2} interchange cost = 0 
Interchange 2: {1, 3, 2} interchange cost = 4 
Interchange 3: {1, 2, 3} interchange cost = 5, 
given a total cost of 9
```

You are to write a program that determines the minimal cost to arrange a specific sequence of numbers.

Edit: The professor does not allow brute forcing.

Comment: are you only allowed to interchange adjacent values?

Comment: No, any elements can be interchanged.

Comment: It's clearly an academic problem - in real life, it is the comparisons that cost a lot, not the exchanges.  In general, an algorithm that minimizes the number of moves of any sort is likely to do better

Comment: Re: "No, any elements can be interchanged"

So 1-2-3 could be converted to 3-2-1 with the single exchange of 1 and 3 for a cost of 4?

Comment: Actually it is very much a real-life problems, even more so than about sorting computer data: imagine it's not about sorting computer data, but reallife objects (eg containers in a shipping yard), where each move incurs a different cost based on location, weight and who knows what else, and performing each move requires way more time than computing the optimal sequence of interchanges in a few seconds.

Comment: So each item has a non-negative cost. Can any item have a cost of 0 or does that not matter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to surprise your professor, you could use [Simulated Annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). Then again, if you manage that, you can probably skip a few courses :). Note that this algorithm will only give an approximate answer.

Otherwise: try a [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm, or [Branch and Bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound). These will both find the optimal answer.

Comment: Oh, man, Annealing! :-) For those who don't know, Annealing is a family of algorithms based on a physical process used to process metal! Can't get any cooler than that! Or, rather, hotter! :-)

Comment: A _probabilistic_ answer to an algorithmic question? Really?

Comment: @sysrqb Well, actually I intended this to be the joke answer :). Then I added the backtracking and branch & bound bit as the "serious afterthought".

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean "brute forcing?"  Do you mean "try all possible combinations and select the cheapest?"  Just checking.

I think "branch and bound" is what you're looking for - check any source on algorithms.  It is "like" brute force, except as you try a sequence of moves, as soon as that sequence of moves is less optimal than any other sequence of moves tried so far, you can abandon the sequence that got you to that point - the cost.  This is one flavor of the "backtracking" mentioned above.

My preferred language for doing this would be Prolog but I'm weird.

Simulated Annealing is a PROBABLISTIC algorithm - if the solution space has local minima, then you may be trapped in one and get what you think is the right answer but isn't.  There are ways around that and the literature all about that can be found but I don't agree that it's the tool you want.

You could try the related genetic algorithms too if that's the way you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

Have you learned trees? You could create a tree with all possible changes leading to the desired result. The trick, of course, is to avoid creating the whole tree -- particularly when a part of it is obviously not the best solution, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think the appropriate approach is to think hard about what defining properties a minimal "cost" sort has. Then figure out the cost by simulating this ideal sort. The key element here is you don't have to implement a general minimal cost sorting algorithm.

For example, let's say the defining property of a minimal cost sort is that every exchange puts at least one of the exchanged element in it's sorted position (I don't know if this is true). Every exchange based sort would love to be able to have this property, but it's not easy(possible?) in the general case. However You can easily create a program that takes an unsorted array, takes the sorted version (which itself can be generated by an unoptimal algorithm), and then using this information decides the minimum cost to achieve the sorted array from the unsorted array.

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

I think the cheapest way to do this is to *swap the cheapest misplaced item with the item that belongs in its spot*. I believe this reduces cost by moving the most expensive things just once. If there are n-elements that are out of place, then there will be at most n-1 swaps to put them in place, at a cost of n-1 * cost of least item + cost of all other out of place.

If the globally cheapest element is not misplaced and the spread between this cheapest one and the cheapest misplaced one is great enough, it can be cheaper to swap the cheapest one in its correct place with the cheapest misplaced one. The cost then is n-1 * cheapest + cost of all out of place + cost of cheapest out of place.

**Example**

For [4,1,2,3], this algorithm exchanges (1,2) to produce:

```
[4,2,1,3]
```

and then swaps (3,1) to produce:

```
[4,2,3,1]
```

and then swaps (4,1) to produce:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Notice that each misplaced item in [2,3,4] is moved only once and is swapped with the lowest cost item.

**Code**

Ooops: "Please don't provide a complete algorithm, just an approach." Removed my code.

Comment: This approach fails for input: [1,8,9,7,6] -- the minimum is 41

Comment: Swaps: (1, 6), (1, 9), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 6). Cost: 41.

Yeah, I considered the possibility that if the least expensive was already in place and there was a big spread between it and the next most expensive, that the solution might be suboptimal, but I couldn't come up with a test case. Thanks, and I'll go back to this.

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to only get you going on it this may not make complete sense.

Determine all possible moves, and the cost for each move and store those somehow, perform the least expensive move, then determine the moves that can be performed from this variation, storing those with the rest of your stored moves, perform the least expensive etc until the array is sorted.

I love solving things like this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also known as the **Silly Sort** problem in some ACM contests. Take a look at [this solution](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~storm/C-files/SillySort.C) using **Divide & Conquer**.

Answer (score -1):

Try different sorting algorithms on the same input data and print the minimum.

Comment: This will not likely produce an optimal solution.